# oninput event in html works fine till <form></form> is added?

Tags: javascript, html

I am adding rows in table and deleting, this works fine. using `oninput=""` event i am also able to calculate the total cost by calling javascript function. 
Now, the moment i add `<form></form>`, neither am able to add rows nor moving any forward. I am new to javascript, and have no clue what is going on. please help somebody.

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Add and Delete Items with Total Cost Value</p>
    <form>
        <div id="tableDiv">
            <table id="myTableHead">
                <tr>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Item Cost</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="ItemName[]" id="ItemName" /></td>
                    <td><input class="ItemCostClass" type="number" name="ItemCost[]" oninput="myTotalFunction()" id="ItemCost" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table id="myTable">

            </table>
            <table id="myTableTot">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Total" value="Total Cost Value --->" readonly /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="TotalValue" id="TotalValue" value=0 readonly /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br>
        <button onclick="myCreateFunction()">Create row</button>
        <button onclick="myDeleteFunction()">Delete row</button>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    function myCreateFunction() {
        var TotalCostValueCurrent = parseFloat(document.getElementById("TotalValue").value);
        if (TotalCostValueCurrent <= 25000) {
            var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
            var row = table.insertRow(-1);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="ItemName[]" id="childItemName" />';
            cell2.innerHTML = '<input class="ItemCostClass" type="number" name="ItemCost[]" oninput="myTotalFunction()" id="childItemCost" />'; 
        } else {
            window.alert("Sorry, You Have Reached Max Shipping Value Limit of 25000, please reduce Pieces to Max Value of 25000");
        }

    }

    function myTotalFunction() {
        var arrItemCost = document.getElementById("tableDiv").getElementsByClassName("ItemCostClass");
        var arrLen = arrItemCost.length;
        var i = 0;
        var itemCostSum = 0;
        while (i <= arrLen && itemCostSum <= 25000) {
            if (itemCostSum <= 25000) {
                itemCostSum = itemCostSum + parseFloat(arrItemCost[i].value);
                i++;
                document.getElementById("TotalValue").value = Math.ceil(itemCostSum); // Update Total Value
            }
        } 
    }

    function myDeleteFunction() {
        var arrItemCost = document.getElementById("tableDiv").getElementsByClassName("ItemCostClass");
        var arrLen = arrItemCost.length;

        var TotalValueCurrent = parseFloat(document.getElementById("TotalValue").value);
        var itemCostFinal = 0;
        itemCostFinal = TotalValueCurrent - parseInt(arrItemCost[arrLen-1].value);

        //FINAL OUTPUT
        document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);   // Delete Last Row
        document.getElementById("TotalValue").value = Math.ceil(itemCostFinal); // Final Cost Value
        document.getElementById("tableDiv").getElementsByClassName("ItemCostClass").pop(); // Drop last value of Item Array
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the form tags buttons tend to do the default action which is submit.

So change your button from,

```
<button onclick="myCreateFunction()">Create row</button>
<button onclick="myDeleteFunction()">Delete row</button>
```

to

```
<input type="button" onclick="myCreateFunction()" value="Create row">
<input type="button" onclick="myDeleteFunction()" value ="Delete row">
```

Comment: No problem always love to help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Input tag instead of button tag. Because button tag in form specifies default submit event on-click so your form submitted when you add any row and also refresh.

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Add and Delete Items with Total Cost Value</p>
  <form>
   <div id="tableDiv">
    <table id="myTableHead">
     <tr>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Item Cost</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="ItemName[]" id="ItemName" /></td>
      <td><input class="ItemCostClass" type="number" name="ItemCost[]" oninput="myTotalFunction()" id="ItemCost" /></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="myTable">

    </table>
    <table id="myTableTot">
     <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="Total" value="Total Cost Value --->" readonly /></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="TotalValue" id="TotalValue" value=0 readonly /></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
   <br>
   <input type="button" onclick="myCreateFunction()" value="Create row" />
   <input type="button" onclick="myDeleteFunction()" value="Delete row" />
  </form>
 </div>

 <script>
 function myCreateFunction() {
  var TotalCostValueCurrent = parseFloat(document.getElementById("TotalValue").value);
  if (TotalCostValueCurrent <= 25000) {
   var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
   var row = table.insertRow(-1);
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
   var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
   cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="ItemName[]" id="childItemName" />';
   cell2.innerHTML = '<input class="ItemCostClass" type="number" name="ItemCost[]" oninput="myTotalFunction()" id="childItemCost" />'; 
  } else {
   window.alert("Sorry, You Have Reached Max Shipping Value Limit of 25000, please reduce Pieces to Max Value of 25000");
  }

 }

 function myTotalFunction() {
  var arrItemCost = document.getElementById("tableDiv").getElementsByClassName("ItemCostClass");
  var arrLen = arrItemCost.length;
  var i = 0;
  var itemCostSum = 0;
  while (i < arrLen && itemCostSum <= 25000) {
   if (itemCostSum <= 25000) {
    itemCostSum = itemCostSum + parseFloat(arrItemCost[i].value);
    i++;
    document.getElementById("TotalValue").value = Math.ceil(itemCostSum); // Update Total Value
   }
  } 
 }

 function myDeleteFunction() {
  var arrItemCost = document.getElementById("tableDiv").getElementsByClassName("ItemCostClass");
  var arrLen = arrItemCost.length;

  var TotalValueCurrent = parseFloat(document.getElementById("TotalValue").value);
  var itemCostFinal = 0;
  itemCostFinal = TotalValueCurrent - parseInt(arrItemCost[arrLen-1].value);

  //FINAL OUTPUT
  document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);   // Delete Last Row
  document.getElementById("TotalValue").value = Math.ceil(itemCostFinal); // Final Cost Value
  document.getElementById("tableDiv").getElementsByClassName("ItemCostClass").pop(); // Drop last value of Item Array
 }
 </script>
```